# web interface for handling Kinect data

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

Currently, there are various tutorials describing how to interact with a Kinect sensor using Windows Forms or WPF for the user interface. But what about using a web interface for handling Kinect data?

Please tell me the best possible way to create web application using c# kinect programming. what browser pluging I need to work wiht kinect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time there is now web interface from MSFT with official SDK, you could use [ZigFu with Unity3D](http://zigfu.com/) if you know these tools.
But in this month MSFT promised to release new version of Kinect SDK with ability to use Kinect in the browser [using HTML5 and CSS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kinectforwindows/archive/2013/06/26/join-now-build-for-tomorrow.aspx)