# Can a web application be developed using Kinect, HTML5 and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, kinect

Is it possible to use Kinect, HTML5, and jQuery with a web application based? There are lot of javascript plugins available for leapmotion. However, I couldn't find any for kinect and web technology.

Comment: Considering it could be done with HTML5 and javascript alone, and jQuery is javascript, sure, you can build a web application with that.

Comment: this might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749002/web-interface-for-handling-kinect-data

Answer (score 1):

You could use this library to pull it off: http://jkinect.com/. I don't think it'll work with the v2 sensor however.

I know in v1 1.8, Microsoft introduced support for HTML5 and javascript applications, but it involves creating a Kinect webserver: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn435664.aspx#step_3